# The name of the data field does not take as lable in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

**Problem:**

I have created a react component and there I am using recharts. I have built a custom tooltip component. There I am checking condition with the label. But It comes to the label as numbers but not as the name which I am providing in the data set. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

This is how my code looks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BarChart,
  Tooltip,
  Bar,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Cell
} from "recharts";

import { Card, CardTitle, CardBody } from "reactstrap";

import "./SessionDuration.css";

const colors = ["#26a0a7", "#79d69f", "#f9ec86", "#ec983d"];

const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  }
];

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
        <p className="intro">{getIntroOfPage(label)}</p>
        <p className="desc">Anything you want can be displayed here.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};

const getIntroOfPage = label => {
  if (label === "Page A") {
    return "Page A is about men's clothing";
  }
  if (label === "Page B") {
    return "Page B is about women's dress";
  }
  if (label === "Page C") {
    return "Page C is about women's bag";
  }
  if (label === "Page D") {
    return "Page D is about household goods";
  }
};

class SessionDuration extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card className="session-duration-card">
        <CardTitle className="session-duration-card-header">
          Session Duration
        </CardTitle>
        <CardBody>
          <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" aspect={4.0 / 5.5}>
            <BarChart
              data={data}
              margin={{
                top: 10,
                right: 5,
                left: 5,
                bottom: 5
              }}
              barGap={10}
            >
              <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />

              <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8">
                {data.map((entry, index) => (
                  <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colors[index]} />
                ))}
              </Bar>
            </BarChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default SessionDuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is issue a in CustomTooltip which not getting label. So you need pass label in there below is given Example

```
<Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip label={name} />} />

//Below is small sample of your code that is working fine
[Codepen] https://codepen.io/dwarka/pen/GeQKXZ
```